# WeMo SDK for iOS Architecture issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to include the WeMo SDK into my existing Xcode project, but it keeps giving compile errors like this one:

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup", referenced from: _encryptPassword in BelkinSDKLibrary.a(OpenSSLEncryption.o) _encryptPasswordWithoutLength in BelkinSDKLibrary.a(OpenSSLEncryption.o)**

My Xcode version is 6.0 and I'm trying to compile for iOS8. I've set the architecture type to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and I've included the following frameworks as another post here suggested:

1. libxml2.dylib
2. CFNetwork.framework
3. MobileCoreServices.framework
4. Security.framework
5. SystemConfiguration.framework

If I create a new project from scratch and include the WeMo SDK libraries, it compiles without issues. The problem only happens when I try to do the same thing with my pre existing project.

I've seen many answers mentioning that when this kind of error happens it's because a .m file is missing from the "compile sources" or because a framework/library is missing. I don't think these are the cases since the exact same libraries that I include in the fresh new project are present in my existing one. Also, I don't see anything unusual in the "compile sources", like a .m file that should be there but is not.

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it is happening, but I'm seeing the same thing. I fixed it by adding libcrypto.a to the target. I'm still getting some duplicate symbol linker errors now, but hopefully this helps you move on from your issue. I had a copy of libcrypto.a lying around from an old WeMo SDK, but you can find and/or build your own on github.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still unable to make it work. I downloaded the OpenSSL for iPhone from gitHub/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone and followed to instructions to install. Nothing changed and I still see the same error. I can't find the file libcrypto.a either.

Comment: @Lightbow, thanks for pointing to the `libcrypto.a` library.  For those who're interested in making wemo SDK work, here is my post to fix all the issues I encountered with it: http://www.egeek.me/2015/03/01/workarounds-for-wemo-ios-sdk/